# Unable to run apt-get in docker mongo initdb script

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I am trying to run an app on minikube. In order to get mongo up, I am running

```
kubectl create configmap mongo-initdb --from-file=importdata.sh
kubectl apply -f mongo.yaml
```

with importdata.sh as:

```
mongo myapp-dev --eval "db.dropDatabase()"

apt-get update && apt-get install curl && apt-get install bzip2

curl https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/xxxxxxxx -o myapp-db.tar.bz2
bzip2 -dc myapp-db.tar.bz2 | tar xvf -
mongorestore --db myapp-dev myapp-dev

mongo myapp-dev --eval 'db.users.update({}, {$set: {hashedPassword: "fwaPwkoIpS4y4aWA+uljXWIlyjTxUzkU+IgK4+B8m+ZhyBrWwM/N/oGfUj0ERAcwnXCOImkOvbvDMH/BAmN8FA==", salt: "YfnL4jUxfbYY6Y3/w8P8KA=="}}, {multi: true})'
mongo myapp-dev --eval 'db.getCollection("users").dropIndex("bad_index1")'
```

and mongo.yaml as:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mongo:3.2
        name: mongo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mongo-initdb
          mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      volumes:
      - name: mongo-initdb
        configMap:
          name: mongo-initdb
```

My goal is to have mongo running with the proper data that I am `curl`ing from that url. However, when I check the logs with `kubectl logs -f deploy/mongo` I see the following:

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/importdata.sh
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.17
connecting to: myapp-dev
2017-10-20T20:00:49.572+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:47118 #2 (1 connection now open)
{ "ok" : 1 }
2017-10-20T20:00:49.576+0000 I NETWORK  [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:47118 (0 connections now open)
E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (13: Permission denied)
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/importdata.sh: line 5: curl: command not found
```

If I add `sudo` before the `apt-get`s, I just get `sudo: command not found` errors.

How can I properly start mongo with my database? I am open to other solutions besides using `curl`.

NOTE:

These commands work if I run `kubectl exec -it mongo-xxxxx bash` and then enter the commands within the pod! Could someone explain the difference between running scripts in the entrypoint and running commands inside the pod?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a ConfigMap for this, I'd recommend you structure the script as something invoked from an initialization container that's run parallel to the container that's hosting MongoDB in the same Pod.

Initialization containers appeared in Kubernetes 1.6, so you'll need at least that version running to take advantage of this - but with a current minikube instance, that shouldn't be an issue. If you're just loading a backup into place, this might be sufficient, but as Janos points out in the comments - these containers all run *before* the pod is "ready" and in sequence before any general containers defined on the pod. These pods also *must* exit prior to the main containers getting control.

You might also be able to leverage teh container lifecycle hooks which aren't guaranteed any ordering prior to the container starting up, but which can do some work between the Pod starting and being marked as "ready" (and hence added to services, etc)

There are 4 documentation points for init containers to give you a good sense of what this is and how to do it:

- [Overview of Init Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/)
- [Example init container with NGINX & wget](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-initialization/)
- [Notes on debugging Init containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-init-containers/)
- [Container Lifecycle Hooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/#define-poststart-and-prestop-handlers)

If you use an init container for this, you'll need the mongod server and its load tools, although I haven't tried that specific process to be able to write out how you'd tackle it.

In a general case, I'd recommend building a container specifically that has the tools you want for doing this data loading - a small container with `bzip2`, `curl`, and a mongodb client, and make the ENTRYPOINT/CMD for that container be the core of the script that you currently have in ConfigMap setup above. However, since init containers would run *before* the mongod is running, that wouldn't do you all that much good...

You could take advantage of the fact that all containers within the same Pod are linked to the same loopback network interface and volumes to communicate with MongoDB and load in the relevant data.

Comment: Note that [Init Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) do not run *parallel* with your normal containers but they run *before* them. (*Sequentially*, if you have multiple Init Containers). So a mongo client in the Init Container will be little help, as the server is not yet running.